# running jar file using php "exec" command takes too long

Tags: php

my jar file simply sends email using SMTP when its executed.
when i run jar using command line it works fine. even when jar file is run using PHP in 
command line it runs fine ("php sendEmail.jar"), but when I try to run it using HTTP server, it will take 5 minutes to run and send an email, why is that?

this is my php line:

```
<?php
exec("java -jar sendEmail.jar" , $output);
echo implode("\n", $output);
?>
```

Comment: consider that you're firing up a complete JVM to do this, each time you call exec()

Comment: the thing is on another machine with the same apache/php/java configuration it runs instantly.

Comment: Maybe it's the `echo` or `implode` that's slow?  Is `passthru("java -jar sendEmail.jar");` any faster? (Note: this will `echo` for you)

Comment: no, passthru, system, exec, shell_exec all take time. a very confusing situation.

Comment: shared server maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php exec() method takes 2 minutes to run a simple jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147003/php-exec-method-takes-2-minutes-to-run-a-simple-jar-file)