# php exec() method takes 2 minutes to run a simple jar file

Tags: java, php, email

this is my code:

```
<?php
exec("java -jar email.jar" , $output);
echo implode("\n", $output);
?>
```

email.jar a a simple smtp email sender. this runs instantly on another machine with exact same java/php/apache configuration. but on this machine, it takes 2 minutes to run the jar file with smtp method. (non-smtp jar files run fast) any clue? why smtp makes it slow?

Comment: It is hard to tell what is causing it to be slow without seeing what email.jar is doing internally.

Comment: it just makes at smtp session and sends an email. nothing major. even php smtp methods run slow. it has something to do with smtp?

Comment: Have you tried other executable? Try out 'echo "hello"' to see if that is already slow. Next, try if java starts up slowly with a hello world java programm. Could it be that the 2 minutes is some timeout and email.jar just sits there and waits while php waits for it for 2 minutes and then kills it? E.g. is email.jar a GUI app?

Comment: nothing else is slow. this smtp jar runs after 2 minutes. is there a way to check php processes on a windows server? like php PID in background and what its doing.